# How do I say the word “bow” in the sentence “I set my bow in the clouds...”?

Tags: pronunciation, heteronyms

How do you pronounce the word "bow" in the following sentence from Genesis 9:13?

> I set my *bow* in the clouds to serve as a sign of my covenant between me and the earth.

Is it pronounced *bow* as in a bow-tie, or is it pronounced *bow* as in bowing to a king?

Comment: There is also a rainbow in Revelation 4:3, the rainbow 'round about the throne in sight like unto an emerald'. http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/66004003

Answer (score 5):

## Arches and arcs, bows and rainbows

This one is actually spelled the way it’s said! It has the GOAT vowel, so it rhymes with the English words *snow* and *no*.  That’s *bow* as in a **bow**-tie or even the **elbow** of your arm, so it’s pronounced /boʊ/ written in the International Phonetic Alphabet (sometimes also transcribed /bow/ phonemically).

That’s because your quote from [Genesis 9:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Genesis%209:13) refers to the **arc** of a **bow**, the one that’s used by hunters. The KJV translation for that verse reads:

> I do set my **bow** in the cloud, and it shall be for a token of a covenant between me and the earth.

[image: double rainbow in Wrangell-St. Elias National Park, Alaska.]
<sup><sub>Image Credit: Eric Rolph’s photo of a double rainbow in Wrangell–St. Elias National Park Alaska [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow)</sub></sup>

Indeed, a rainbow is itself the arc of a circle:

[image: arc of a circle]

The arc is the round part, the chord (string) would be the line connecting the endpoints — which is why in Spanish they call a rainbow an [*arcoíris*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arco_iris#Spanish), meaning Iris’s arc. It was so named after [the Greek goddess of the rainbow, Iris](http://www.theoi.com/Pontios/Iris.html), who was Hera’s handmaiden and messenger.

Even English has used *Iris* to mean the rainbow. Caxton back in 1490 wrote that:

> **Yris**..is the **rayen bowe** wyth hir fayr cote of dyuerse fygures.

(Read: Iris..is the rainbow with her fair coat of diverse figures.)

Shakespeare himself used *Iris* this way, something of a Hellenistic personification to  refer to the rainbow, when in 1609 he wrote in *Troilus and Cressida*:

> His crest that prouder then blew **Iris** bends.

Later in *All’s Well That Ends Well* he wrote of *Iris* in a more figurative sense as a halo of prismatic colors:

> What's the matter, That this distempered messenger of wet? The manie colour'd **Iris** rounds thine eye?

### Historical associations

The rainbow has ancient associations with divine messages, both in English and elsewhere. A Middle English reference from the 1300s speaks of the rainbow as Juno’s (Roman for Greek Hera’s) messenger. In the [Theoi Project’s article on the goddess](http://www.theoi.com/Pontios/Iris.html), they write:

> For the coastal-dwelling Greeks, the **rainbow’s arc** was most often seen spanning the distance beteween cloud and sea, and so the goddess was believed to replenish the rain-clouds with water from the sea.

Indeed in Spanish, Genesis 9:13 runs something like this:

> Mi **arco** pondré en las nubes, el cual será por señal de convenio entre mí y la tierra.

The Latin Vulgate for that verse also used **arc** as in an arch or a bow, reading:

> **Arcum** meum ponam in nubibus et erit signum foederis inter me et inter terram.

The use of the word *arc* for a curve in the sky was not unique to the Romance languages. Geoffery Chaucer writing in Middle English referred to the heavenly arc in his *Merchant’s Tale* from around 1386:

> Parfourmed hath the sonne his **ark** diourne.

That’s Middle English for what we might today write *“The sun has performed his diurnal **arc**.”* That’s in fact the first citation of the word used for celestial courses in English per the OED. The word *bow* had for ages been used for the rainbow itself, for even more anciently in Old English Ælfric translated a bit of that part of Genesis that you reference as:

> Æteowþ min **boᵹa** on ðam wolcnum.

In other copies of the verse translated into Old English, we find *renboᵹan* used for *rainbow* instead:

> Ic sette minne **renboᵹan** [L. ***arcum*** meum] on wolcnum.

(*Wolcnum* in Old English was the dative plural of a word meaning the heavens or skies.)

As you see, Old English spelled it *boᵹa* but that G was weak, so this developed first into Middle English’s *boȝe, bouwe, boghe* and then into Modern English *bow*. That original G from Old English can still be seen in some of English’s Germanic cousins: German has *Bogen* for it, Dutch *boog*,  and Norwegian *boge*, but Danish like English has lost the G leaving Danish with only *bue* in that language.

The *rain-* part of *rainbow* came later; as just shown above, Old English just had (its spelling of) *bow* to mean *rainbow*, a use still sometimes found even in later versions of English. Poets have historically used *bow* to mean *rainbow*:

> - **1667**   Milton *Paradise Lost* xi. 865 —  A dewie Cloud, and in the Cloud a Bow .
> - **1728**   J. Thomson *Spring* 13 —  Bestriding Earth, the grand ætherial Bow.
> - **1850**   Tennyson *In Memoriam* cxx. 189  — Every dew-drop paints a bow.

Comment: Up-voted for the answer, but I would have, anyway, for the stunning picture.

Comment: At least in the original Hebrew, קשת means both "arc" and "bow" in Ancient and Modern Hebrew.  it's only when you translate it to English, you need to choose between those two.